# Is the only way to add a quicklaunch in LXQt by mouse?

Tags: panel, lxqt

I try to add a quicklaunch item to the panel in Lubuntu 18.10. This seems only to work with drag and drop from the start menu and not via a menu for the panel setting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's correct; as of LXQt 0.13 there is no way to modify this within the LXQt Panel settings; it's mouse only.

Comment: Even as mouse-only the behaviour is a bit strange. I seem to be able to use mouse to drag an application icon to Desktop only. Then from Desktop I can drag it to the panel. If I then delete the Desktop icon, the panel icon also stops working but stays there. Dragging directly to panel didn't work for me, or I couldn't figure out the right way.

Comment: Thanks @icarus74  
your suggestion to use intermediate icon on Desktop does the trick .  
otherwise  
when directly dragging icon from e.g. `PCMan File Manager`  
( as it supposed to work or expected in previous releases )   
I got misleading: [`cannot be embedded into QuickLaunch for now`](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/235)  
and [official docs](https://manual.lubuntu.me/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=quick%20launch) would not help either .

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, it should read like this:

```
[quicklaunch]

alignment=Left

apps\1\desktop=/usr/share/applications/pcmanfm-qt.desktop

apps\2\desktop=/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

apps\3\desktop=/usr/share/applications/qterminal.desktop 

apps\size=3 

type=quicklaunch
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in Lubuntu 19.04 to get the qterminal into the panel by changing the quicklaunch-section in the file "~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf":

```
[quicklaunch] alignment=Left
apps\1\desktop=/usr/share/applications/pcmanfm-qt.desktop
apps\2\desktop=/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
apps\3\desktop=/usr/share/applications/qterminal.desktop 
apps\size=3
> type=quicklaunch
```

Comment: You should be able to delete this post, since you've posted a different one. Alternatively, when answer is downvoted users can vote to delete the post. If you see a downvote plus delete vote, don't worry about the -1 points.

Answer (score 0):

**Is the only way to add a quicklaunch in LXQt by mouse?** (understood as drag-and-drop)

**NO**

What I just did in Lubuntu 20.04:

1. Right click on the panel -> *Configure panel*
2. Select *Widgets*
3. Select *+* (Add widget)
4. Select *Quick launch*. This opens a new group of quick launch icons. Select the terminal icon from the menu.

That's it.
You could check the contents of `~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf`, under sections `[quicklaunch]` and `[quicklaunch2]`, to understand the implied changes.
This is what I obtained

```
[quicklaunch2]
alignment=Left
apps\1\desktop=/usr/share/applications/qterminal.desktop
apps\size=1
type=quicklaunch
```

Manual modifications suggested in other answers are consistent with this.