# How to add terminal in quick launcher

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, lxde

Recently i installed Lubutu, every time I have go to application menu then system tools then terminal for launch terminal, I want to access terminal in one click, In Ubuntu there was an option "Add to favourites" for add any application to quick- launcher if we right click on opened application in launcher.

I am using Lubuntu first time. I did not find a way to add qterminal in quick launcher. How to add applications on taskbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add programs to the Unity Launcher or Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224004/how-to-add-programs-to-the-unity-launcher-or-ubuntu-dock)

Comment: _Praveen Yadav_, would you please look at http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201010/images/panel-10.png from http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201010/page07.html (an article on LXpanel) and tell me if you want to add a button to the Application Launcher Bar section of the panel for for lxterminal https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal ?

Comment: @Inmate4587 it's not duplicate, link you provided is for Ubuntu not for Lubuntu please delete your comment

Comment: See [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085371/is-the-only-way-to-add-a-quicklaunch-in-lxqt-by-mouse/1126226#1126226](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085371/is-the-only-way-to-add-a-quicklaunch-in-lxqt-by-mouse/1126226#1126226) for a good solution

Answer (score 6):

For lubuntu 18.10, drag and drop from the start menu to the quick launch bar.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 3 solutions for you:

1. Use CTRL+ALT+T keyboard shortcut. It launches a terminal from anywhere you are.
2. Launch a Terminal from the menu. Once it is launched, it appears in the task bar. In the task bar, right click on the terminal icon and select "Add to launchbar"
3. Right-click on launchbar, go to "Settings" (the first entry):
   [image]
   and then add the terminal to the taskbar with the dedicated menu:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Lubuntu 20.04, the only way I was able to do this is by;

1. Click on Menu
2. Select the application you want
3. Drag it and drop it on the quicklauncher

Comment: you can't use search to find the app, you have to find it manually, and then drag it to quicklaunch